# Snowflake Scripting - EXECUTE IMMEDIATE multiple statements to drop tables without loop/cursor

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The goal is go drop multiple tables that matches a specific naming pattern using only SQL without cursors/loops:

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_1(i INT);
CREATE TABLE tab_2(i INT);
CREATE TABLE tab_3(i INT);
CREATE TABLE tab_4(i INT);
CREATE TABLE tab_5(i INT);
```

Normally it could be done by generating query first:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', TABLE_NAME, ';', CHAR(10)) ,'')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC'
  AND TABLE_NAME ILIKE 'TAB!_%' ESCAPE '!'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(());
/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TAB_1; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TAB_2; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TAB_3; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TAB_4; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TAB_5; 
*/
```

**Then the output needs to be copied and run. This manual step is unecessary and should be avoided.**

The idea was to use `SELECT INTO` and `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to invoke  generated query:

```
DECLARE 
    QUERY STRING;
BEGIN
    SELECT LISTAGG(CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', TABLE_NAME, ';', CHAR(10)), '')
    INTO :QUERY
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC'
      AND TABLE_NAME ILIKE 'TAB!_%' ESCAPE '!'
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(());

  QUERY := COALESCE(QUERY, 'SELECT ''No tables found''');

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
  RETURN :QUERY;
END;
```

This is not possible:

> Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to wrap generated code with BEGIN END block:

```
DECLARE 
    QUERY STRING;
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT('BEGIN', CHAR(10)
             ,LISTAGG(CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', TABLE_NAME, ';', CHAR(10)), '')
             ,'END')
    INTO :QUERY
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC'
      AND TABLE_NAME ILIKE 'TAB!_%' ESCAPE '!'
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(());

  QUERY := COALESCE(QUERY, 'SELECT ''No tables found''');

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
  RETURN :QUERY;
END;
```

Output:

```
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TAB_1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TAB_2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TAB_3;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TAB_4;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TAB_5;
END

SHOW TABLES LIKE 'TAB_%';
-- no resultset
```

[image]

And second run:

[image]